# How test directive with Renderer2?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing

I have created a small directive that prevents default of event(s) passed to it.

```ts
@Directive({
    selector: '[sPreventDefault]'
})
export class PreventDefaultDirective {
    private events: (() => void)[] = [];
    @Input('sPreventDefault') set listenOn(events: string | string[]) {
        this.removeListeners();

        if (typeof events == 'string') {
            events = [events];
        }
        this.registerEventListener(
            events,
            e => {
                if (e instanceof Event) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                } else {
                    e.srcEvent.stopPropagation();
                }
            },
        );
    }

    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, private renderer: Renderer2) {
        super(elementRef, renderer);
    }

    protected registerEventListener(listenOn: string[], eventListener: (e: Event | HammerJSEvent) => void): void {
        this.events = listenOn.map(eventName => {
            return this.renderer.listen(this.elementRef.nativeElement, eventName, eventListener);
        });
    }
    protected removeListeners(): void {
        this.events.forEach(dispose => dispose());
        this.events = [];
    }
}
```

Test suit

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'test-host',
    template: `<div [sPreventDefault]="events">`,
})
class TestHostComponent {
    @ViewChild(PreventDefaultDirective) directive!: PreventDefaultDirective;
    @Input() events: PreventDefaultDirective['listenOn'] = [];
}

fdescribe('PreventDefaultDirective', () => {
    let host: TestHostComponent;
    let hostElement: DebugElement;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestHostComponent>;
    let directive: PreventDefaultDirective;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                TestHostComponent,
                PreventDefaultDirective,
            ],
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestHostComponent);
        hostElement = fixture.debugElement;
        host = fixture.componentInstance;
        directive = host.directive;
    }));

    it('should create an instance', () => {
        host.events = ['testEvent'];
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should add listener', () => {
        host.events = ['testEvent'];
        fixture.detectChanges();

        //  DebugElement.listeners is null
        expect(hostElement.listeners.length).toBe(1);
        expect(hostElement.listeners.map(l => l.name)).toBe(host.events);
    });
});
```

My problem is, that `DebugElement`, does not seems to know about events registered via `Renderer2.listen` method. What is the right way to test this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok since got interested I checked some things but it won't be straight answer or even solution to your problem although you can find something useful.

It looks like `hostElement.listeners` points to event listeners added by `@HostListener` decorator, you can easily check that.
I've also try to find way to retrieve listeners but without success.

What I would do here is to check whenever `renderer.listen` was called and leave implementation behind - this way could be wrong for testing higher than "unit tests" since you want to check if this really works but for unit it should be fine. If you want to spy on `Renderer2` you can do this:

```
const renderer = fixture.componentRef.injector.get(Renderer2);
const listenSpy = spyOn(renderer, 'listen');
expect(listenSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Edit 1:
Since provided way of getting `Renderer2` is deprecated this should be used:

```
const renderer = fixture.componentRef.injector.get(Renderer2 as Type<Renderer2>);
```

Comment: This actually worked, I totally forgot about injector! I would only like to ask about the deprecation, it seems as false positive to me, but one is never sure. Error: `get is deprecated: from v4.0.0 use Type<T> or InjectionToken<T> (deprecation)`

Comment: About the rest, you are totally correct, yet I wanted to test if it is being called, cleaned up and if it actually prevents default. All of that can be done via spies.

Comment: @Akxe you are right, with this it shouldn't complain anymore: `const renderer = fixture.componentRef.injector.get<Renderer2>(Renderer2 as Type<Renderer2>);`

Comment: True, but you don't need `<Renderer2>`, as the type definition of `get` infers the type from generic of `Type<T>`. Yet I am not sure why this is necessary  It is Angular component!